# $\max _{x \in \mathbb{R}_{+*}^{3 \times 1}} x_{2}+x_{3}$ subject to $4 x_{1}=\left(x_{2}^{2}+x_{1} x_{3}\right)\left(x_{1}+x_{3}\right)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem of maximization that goes as follows:
$$
\max _{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}} x_{2}+x_{3} \text { subject to } 4 x_{1}=\left(x_{2}^{2}+x_{1} x_{3}\right)\left(x_{1}+x_{3}\right), x_{1}>0, x_{2}>0 \text { and } x_{3}>0
$$
I want to go with a classical approach to solve it, and no specific algorithms. First restriction is that I have to solve this problem **without** thinking about KKT conditions ( I don't even know if it is solvable in that manner ). I wanted use inequalities and try to restrain the domain of the constraints, with no results.

Any suggestions to an approach ??

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without the KKT conditions if you add slack variables to convert the inequalities into equalities. Then you use Lagrange multipliers.

\begin{align*}
\max\, & x_2 + x_3\\
\textrm{s.t.} &\\
& 4x_1 -(x_2^2+x_1 x_3)(x_1+x_3)=0\\
& x_1 - s_1^2 = 0\\
& x_2 - s_2^2=0\\
& x_3 - s_3^2=0
\end{align*}